# Regex Python validating an email

Tags: python, regex

I'm having loads of trouble trying to fulfill the requirements of this regex as stated below.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}|^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}[\-\_]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}@[A-Za-z0-9][\-\_]{5,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

"*Your Email and Re-enter email must not be blank and must have the form `acct@domain` where*:

- `acct`

  1. *1 or more characters*
  2. *Composed of only upper or lowercase alphabetic characters,*
     *numeric characters, dashes, periods, underscores and hyphens*
  3. *Contains no embedded blanks.*
  4. *Cannot start or end with an underscore, dash, period or hyphen.*
  5. *There must be at least two letters before and after every period.*

---

- `domain`

  1. *5 or more characters*
  2. *Composed of only upper or lowercase alphabetic characters, numeric characters, dashes, periods, and hyphens, underscores*
  3. *Contains no embedded blanks*
  4. *Must have at least one period, and cannot start or end with an underscore, dash, period or hyphen.*
  5. *There must be at least two letters before and after every period.*

---

- The email address must contain an `@` between **acct** and **domain**

Sample valid email addresses:

```
a@aa.ca, a@aaAAA-c.cc_3.com
```

Sample invalid email addresses:

```
b@b, b@b.b, b@bb.bb!c
```

*Both email addresses must be the same"*

Comment: Is this homework? Underscore `_` is not a valid character in a domain name.

Comment: Yeah, but according to the requirements it is... So frustrated!!!

Comment: My advice about regular expressions and email: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: I would avoid using regex to validate emails. That said, if you have to, you should look into https://www.debuggex.com/. It will help you make a good regex and unit test it for thoroughness.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the regex which can validate all your criteria and I hope it is also more efficient.

```
^(?![\W_])((?:([\w-]{2,})\.?){1,})(?<![\W_])@(?![\W_])(?=[\w.-]{5,})(?=.+\..+)(?1)(?<![\W_])$
```

Look at the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aR4hJ0/1) for detailed overview.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this as it was the closest, and used a new world of regular expressions for me. Through thorough research, I was able to understand how this worked and modified it to suit the requirements. The tools regex101 and debuggex are amazing as well and I wouldn't have discovered them if it wasn't for the help of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can be dramatically simplified (probably even more so than this example), but then since your criteria is actually a little more sophisticated than your examples let on:

```
^[a-z]([\w-]*[a-z]|[\w-.]*[a-z]{2,}|[a-z])*@[a-z]([\w-]*[a-z]|[\w-.]*[a-z]{2,}|[a-z]){4,}?\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/gE4wK2/2 (note the case-insensitive option too)

Where the larger problem lies, however, is the discrepancies in the valid samples you've provided.

**Account:**

- 1 or more characters

  - `[a-z]` ensures there is at least one character exists in the account
- composed of only upper or lowercase letters, numbers, periods, underscores and hyphens, and contains no whitespace

  - `([\w-]*)` ensures that you *can* have any letter or hyphen
- cannot start or end with an underscore, hyphen, or period

  - `([a-z]|[a-z])*` ensures that the last character, if it exists, is a letter
- there must be at least **two letters before and after every period**

  - `[\w-.]*[a-z]{2,}` ensures that if there's a period, there must be two letters following it.

Already you can see that your examples like `a@aa.ca` shouldn't match.

**@ symbol must exist between account and domain**

- That's easy: there's an `@` literal in the expression.

**Domain:**

- 5 or more characters

  - `(...big long expression...){4,}` ensures that there are 4 additional characters after the initial domain letter (total of 5)
- composed of only upper or lowercase alphabetic characters, numeric characters, hyphens, periods, and underscores and contains no white space

  - `([\w-]*[a-z])` nails that one
- must have at least one period

  - There's a period literal in the expression `\.`
- cannot start or end with an underscore, hyphen, or period

  - `[a-z]` ensures the first character of the domain is a letter
- there must be at least **two letters before and after every period**

  - `[\w-.]*[a-z]{2,}` if there's a period in the string, 2 letters must follow
  - `[a-z]{2,}$` ensures that there are at least two letters following the domain period

> All of this however, and I still advocate against complex regular expressions to validate email addresses: read http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/
>
> In the end, check for a super basic email address like `^.*?@.*?\..*?$` and just send the thing!

Comment: You have NO IDEA how happy I am... Thank you all for the amazing resources as well that will help contribute to successful regex construction!!!! those websites are amazing!

Comment: You're welcome ;) Do not go do not go gentle into that good black hole of regex email validation